# .net core get RemoteIpAddress.MapToIPv4() that is behind cloudflare proxy

Tags: asp.net-core

I need to extract the user IP address (v4).
I have the following code to do so:

```
 HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.MapToIPv4().ToString();
```

The problem is that in this case I am getting cloud flare ip address.

How can I get the forwarded v4 IP address?

Thanks

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: @rolls something like that: `string header = (context.Request.Headers["CF-Connecting-IP"].FirstOrDefault() ?? context.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].FirstOrDefault());
                if (IPAddress.TryParse(header, out IPAddress ip))
                {
                    return ip;
                }`

Comment: Found the cloudflare documentation showing all of their specific cloudflare headers that are added.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudflare passes all HTTP request headers to your origin web server and adds additional headers.

The header:

> CF-Connecting-IP
>
> provides the client IP address connecting to Cloudflare to the origin
> web server.

You can also use the header:

> X-Forwarded-For
>
> which maintains proxy server and original visitor IP addresses.

For more information about the CloudFlare headers you can refer to the [documentation](https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/get-started/reference/http-request-headers/)

Actually, you can created a method that tries to check all these headers and return the client IP address value.

```cs
private string getRemoteIpAddress(HttpContext accessor) {
    // try reading the CloudFlare client IP address header
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessor.Request.Headers["CF-CONNECTING-IP"])) 
        return accessor.Request.Headers["CF-CONNECTING-IP"];
    // try reading the proxy server and original visitor IP addresses header
    var ipAddress = accessor.GetServerVariable("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"); 
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress)) { 
        var addresses = ipAddress.Split(','); 
        if (addresses.Length != 0) return addresses.Last(); 
    }
    // try reading the remote IpAddress without a proxy
    return accessor.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString(); 
}
```